# Can I Limit Value used by python in Uri of an Api Gateway

Tags: python

Asking a new question as my original was closed by admin who said a similar question had the answer. I checked it and it didnt have the answer. That answer was related to user input in Python itself. I am using a front end in the form of an Api Uri which I have included in this question.

In my code below I use this to call an Api using 'Method' and 'Value' parameters. For example on the URL they use to call the Api they enter Method2=Min and Value2=2 This works fine and allows the user to input whatever they want into Value2 so they can change the settings of an AutoScaling Group.

If the user makes a mistake and inputs Value as 100 instead of 10 in the Uri, for example Value3=100, I would not want the Autoscaling Group Max size to change to 100. Therefore is there of editing my script so I can stop that Max size from changing to 100? Like some sort of max size value in the script itself?

To invoke the Api I use powershell command like this

invoke-webrequest -Uri 'https://name-of-api.amazonaws.com/?TagKey=tag-key-name&TagValue=tag-value-name&Method1=Capacity&Value1=1&Method2=Min&Value2=1&Method3=Max&Value3=4' -Headers @{"X-Api-Key"="name-of-api-key"}

As you can see the user has the power to change 'Method3=Max' to have a 'Value3' of 100 if they want

Thanks

```
import boto3
import botocore
import os
import json
import logging

# Set up logger.
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# Set up clients.
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')


def handler(event, context):
# Step one: get all AutoScaling Groups.
    response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
        MaxRecords=100
    )

    # Make an empty list for ASG info storage.
    allAutoScaling = [] # empty list of no items.

    # Get the initial results and posts them to CloudWatch logs
    allAutoScaling.append(response['AutoScalingGroups'])
    logger.info(allAutoScaling)

    # If 'Marker' is present in the response, we have more to get.
    while 'Marker' in response:
        old_marker = response['Marker']
        response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
            MaxRecords=100,
            Marker = old_marker
        )
        allAutoScaling.append(response['AutoScalingGroups'])
    
        # Cycles back up to repeat the pagination.

    # Now to find the tags specified in the Api Uri
    for autoscaling in allAutoScaling:
        for key in autoscaling:
           for tag in key['Tags']:
               if tag['Key'] == event['TagKey'] and tag['Value'] == event['TagValue']:
       
                if event['Method2'] == "Min":
                     if event['Value2']: 
                        Value2 = int(event['Value2'])
                        response = client.update_auto_scaling_group(
                        AutoScalingGroupName=key['AutoScalingGroupName'],    
                        MinSize=Value2
                        )
                else:
                    print('Min already at required level')
                    
                
                
                if event['Method3'] == "Max":
                     if event['Value3']: 
                        Value3 = int(event['Value3'])
                        response = client.update_auto_scaling_group(
                        AutoScalingGroupName=key['AutoScalingGroupName'],    
                        MaxSize=Value3
                        )
                else:
                    print('Max already at required level')
                    
                if event['Method1'] == "Capacity":
                      if event['Value1']: 
                         Value1 = int(event['Value1'])
                         response = client.set_desired_capacity(
                         AutoScalingGroupName=key['AutoScalingGroupName'],
                         DesiredCapacity=Value1
                         )
                else:
                    print('Capacity already at required level')
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you ask. Isn't your API supposed to check the value they get and return a message accordingly e.g. wrong value? Where do you expect to "limit to 10 what they can enter" - in the URI? i.e. they can make whatever request they want, it's up to you to handle wrong input you get.

Comment: If the user makes a mistake and inputs Value as 100 instead of 10 in the Uri, for example Value3=100  Therefore my script needs to prohibit them from actually changing the ASG max size to 100 because the max size it can be is 10. Ive tried a while loop but as Im new to python that didnt work for me

Comment: That is exactly what I say - your script should handle the wrong input, not limit them to enter certain values. They can make whatever request they want, your handler should act accordingly.

Comment: At the start of the script you can check the parameters you get. Most trivial check would use simple `if` block... What you want to do in case of wrong input is up to you.

Comment: I tried this but it just looped through everything   while True:
        try:
            Value3 = int(event['Value3'])
            if Value3 < 1 or Value3 > 10:
                break
        
        except ValueError:
          print("Invalid integer. The number must be in the range of 1-10.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something within these lines:

```
try:
    value = int(event['Value3'])
except ValueError:
    print(f"{event['Value3']} is not a valid integer")
else:
    if 1 <= value <= 3:
        # do something, process the request
    else:
        print(f'Value must be between 1 and 3, got {value} instead')
```

Comment: Thanks. The try block worked. I just had to define the name 'Value' at if 1 <= value <= 3:

Comment: `value` is defined in the `try` block. If it errors it will execute the `except` block and not the `else` block.